# Maven: difference between <directory> and <outputDirectory> under <build> tag

Tags: maven, maven-3

In Maven, under "build" tag we have "directory" and "outputDirectory" , when i set both of them to different directories, the directory specified in the "outputDirectory" is taken as target directory. I also observed that the directory specified in the outputDirectory can be configured as the sub directories to the direcotry specified under "directory" tag, but in this case i can use "directory" itself to specify my sub directories also. Do we have any specific usage to these two tags

Answer (score 0):

```
<build>
<directory>target</directory>
<outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
```

See Super pom : https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html

Answer (score 0):

Maven compiler plugin puts compiled classes into `project.build.outputDirectory`

Surefire plugin runs tests using project classes in `project.build.outputDirectory`

Jar plugin gathers files from `project.build.outputDirectory` and puts the resulting jar into `project.build.directory`

Install plugin takes jar from `project.build.directory`

`project.build.outputDirectory` needs to be different from `project.build.directory` because `project.build.directory` contains files other than compiled classes and these files will be mistakenly grabbed by plugins (e.g. jar plugin) expecting only compiled classes.

By default `project.build.outputDirectory` is a subdirectory of `project.build.directory` ( `target/classes` and `target` respectively).
Generally it is not recommended to change the default values of these properties and usually there is no need to do so.